# Which version of AEM supports .cfg.json config files?

Tags: osgi, aem

So, https://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/configuration-installer-factory.html tells us that the currently recommended way to configure OSGi components is to use `.cfg.json` files. However, it notes that those are only supported “[…] since Installer Configuration Factory 1.2.0”.

So now I’d like to know:

1. How do I figure out which version of “Installer Configuration Factory” my AEM uses?
2. Which version of AEM comes preinstalled with Installer Configuration Factory ≥ 1.2.0?
3. If I’m on an older version of AEM, how do I upgrade Installer Configuration Factory?

I couldn’t find definite answers on any of these. But Adobe does sometimes also recommend using .cfg.json config files but only in articles about AaaCS. Is this only supported on AaaCS?

Sorry for my snarky tone but the lack of reliable, concise documentation is infuriating…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How do I figure out which version of “Installer Configuration Factory” my AEM uses?

- goto /system/console/bundles
- search for `Apache Sling Installer Configuration Admin Support`
- This gives you the bundle you are looking for
  [image]
  The number as marked in screenshot is the version used by your AEM.

> Which version of AEM comes preinstalled with Installer Configuration Factory ≥ 1.2.0?

I am on AEM 6.5.6 and the screenshot above is from the same instance. It exports out 1.1.2. The only version above this is 6.5.7, not sure if it has been upgraded to 1.2.0 as you need

> If I’m on an older version of AEM, how do I upgrade Installer Configuration Factory?

You can build the bundle or download the already available one and install. However if there is any hard dependency on the existing version, your instance may corrupt. In order to avoid that, you may need to evaluate what all bundles are dependent on the existing version of configuration bundle and see if you can upgrade them all.

Short cut is to create a vanilla instance and deploy the configuration bundle exporting 1.2.0 version of configuration and test if instance comes up and number of active bundles is same and the ones before you upgraded configurations bundle.

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth reply. Never in a million years would I have guessed that “Configuration Installer Factory” and “Installer Configuration Admin Support” are the same thing. One sounds like it would be the installer for a configuration whereas the other would be the configuration for the installer…